# Maximizing summation function with upper bound as variable.

Tags: optimization, summation

I'm trying to find the general way of optimizing a summation function and I'm a bit lost. I would like to find the maxium (and the minimum, ideally) of:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{x} f(n)$$

For example, let's say:

$$ f(n) = -(n-4)^2 + 16 $$

In this scenario, the answer is easy to find without doing any work: f(n) is positive for $n \in [0, 8]$, and then becomes negative for infinity, we can maximize the sum by adding all positive numbers ($x = 8$).

Is there a way to find this mathematically, in a general way for all functions? Usually when looking to optimize a function I would take the derivative, but the derivative of a summation doesn't make much sense, does it?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can derive the summation, as long as it is finite.

Comment: Can you please remove the "accepted" tick from my answer? It isn't right, works by chance. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a local max at positive integer $x$, you want $f(x) \ge 0$ while $f(x+1) \le 0$.  Similarly for a local min with $\le$ and $\ge$.  So you look for the places where $f$ changes sign.

Comment: Say for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can easily determine a sufficiently large $K(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\left| \sum_{n = K(\epsilon)}^\infty f(n)\right| < \epsilon,$ do you have any ideas on methods for efficiently finding a solution which is within $\epsilon$ of global optimality?

Comment: In general (i.e. if all you can do is evaluate $f$ at given values), then no: the best you can do is a brute-force search of $n = 0$ to $K(\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Attention, please**: this solution works by chance. It isn't by any means right. Sorry.

---

When your summation is finite, you can take its derivative, and
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^x f(n)\right)^\prime = \sum_{n=0}^x f^\prime(n).
$$

Assuming $f(n) = -(n-4)^2 + 16$, we obtain $f^\prime(n) = -2n + 8$ and
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^x f(n)\right)^\prime = \sum_{n=0}^x f^\prime(n) = 8x
- 2\sum_{n=0}^x n,
$$
which equals to $8x - x^2 - x = -x^2 + 7x$.

Solving for $x$, we find that
$$
\begin{aligned}
x(7-x) = 0 &\implies x = 0 \lor x = 7 \\
x(7-x) \ge 0 &\implies x \in [0,8). 
\end{aligned}
$$

Why did $7$ come out, instead of $8$? My guess: for $n = 8$, $f(n)$ equals zero, meaning that the $8$-th term of the summation does not provide any contribute, so the local maximum is at $n = 7$.

Comment: I'm confused. He is trying to maximize over $x$ yet you seem to be differentiating w.r.t. $n$? Am I missing something obvious? I believe the OP was referring to $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^x f(n)$$ in the question (which would, of course, be $f(x)$ under suitable conditions if we extended the summation to an integral).

Comment: To me, it seemed quite natural to derive first, and sum then. Doing the opposite brings almost the same result ($-x^2 + 7x -23/6$). To be honest, the more I ruminate on this, the more I get confused, too.

Comment: The problem is your differentiation is with respect to the wrong variable -- not that you are differentiating in the wrong order (differentiation is a linear operator). Your method worked by coincidence, it does not work in general. Consider $f(n) = (n-6)(n+4)$, then the summation is minimized at $x \in \{5,6\}$. However, note $$\frac{d}{dn}f(n) = 2n-2,$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^x 2n-2$$ is monotone non-decreasing over the positive integers.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the provided example, it made me understand what you meant in the previous comment. I'll leave the answer because I think it's useful to help others avoid this kind of mistake, and I'll request the OP to remove the green tick from this.